# RSS Feed Parsing

Tags: java, parsing, rss

Im trying to retrieve the RSS feed from new.google.com, Im using working with the top stories feed right now: http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss

I can retrieve and process it right, using: http://pastebin.com/YDNPXyVK

Here is my log of what im getting: http://pastebin.com/a5HRsatX, it seems when there is an apostrophe it stops...

I thank you for any help you can offer me.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to use the ROME library. Here's an example:

```
package com.infosys.hanumant.rome;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndEntry;
import com.sun.syndication.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.sun.syndication.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.sun.syndication.io.XmlReader;

/**
 * @author Hanumant Shikhare
 */
public class Reader {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url  = new URL("http://example.com/feed.xml");
    XmlReader reader = null;

    try {
      reader = new XmlReader(url);
      SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedInput().build(reader);
      System.out.println("Feed Title: "+ feed.getAuthor());

      for (Iterator i = feed.getEntries().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        SyndEntry entry = (SyndEntry) i.next();
        System.out.println(entry.getTitle());
      }
    } finally {
      if (reader != null)
        reader.close();
      }
    }
}
```

The example is copied from [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/04/reading-parsing-rss-feed-using-rome.html).

Comment: ROME will even make heroic attempts to deal with invalid RSS feeds. I think its worth the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

try using [this lib](https://github.com/matshofman/Android-RSS-Reader-Library) to parse the xml feed, it works great!